# Behavior of IPSec when receive window gets full

Tags: ipsec

How does IPSec behave when an incoming package can't be marked received in the receive window without the receive window being moved in such a way that a not-yet received package's spot is pushed out of the window?

Comment: This topic would fit better on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anti-replay window is moved, the new upper bound will be the sequence number of the received package (it's always the highest sequence number of any successfully validated package). Packets received later with sequence numbers lower than the new lower bound of the window will be dropped. Refer to [RFC 4303, section 3.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4303#section-3.4.3) for details.